# Why does ostream_iterator not work as expected?

Tags: c++, stream

Needless to say any more than the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<char, char> PAIR;

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const PAIR& r)
{
    return os << r.first;
}

int main() 
{
    vector<PAIR> coll; 

    cout << coll[0]; // OK. 

    // The following line will cause a compilation error! Why???
    copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), ostream_iterator<PAIR>(cout)); 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the name lookup does not find your `operator<<(ostream& os, const PAIR& r)`. The code that tries to invoke the `operator<<` is in somewhere inside the `ostream_iterator<>` which is itself inside the `std` namespace. The name lookup looks around for the right function inside `ostream_iterator<>` and the `std` namespace; the argument dependent lookup does not help here because both of the parameters are in the `std` namespace, too.

So, my suggestion is (1) either to wrap your operator into `namespace std { }`, but that is UB, IIRC. Or (2) create a struct inheriting from `std::pair` to define a new type in your namespace, and using the ADL to find your `operator<<()`.

**UPDATE:**

My 3rd suggestion is to use a custom manipulator to print out the pair.

As for my 2nd suggestion, if you can use C++11, inheriting from `std::pair` should be easy (untested):

```
struct PAIR : std::pair
{
  using std::pair::pair;
};
```

If you cannot use C++11, then I suggest using a custom manipulator.

Answer (score 10):

This is a common problem : in a word, your `operator<<` is not seen when instantiating `std::ostream_iterator`.

During instantiation, name lookup attempts to find an `operator<<` in the namespace `std`. Candidates will be found, so no other namespaces will be considered (and, particularly, not the global namespace). Then, overload resolution comes into play : none of the overload matches the argument type, so compilation fails. Note that argument dependent lookup is not of any help here as `std::pair` also is in namespace `std`.

You have two solutions :

- Enclose your `operator<<` in `namespace std { }`, although you should know that **this is illegal according to the standard** (17.4.3.1)
- Avoid `std::copy` for this task and use `std::for_each` (either with an 'old-fashioned' functor or lambda)

Comment: @icecrime, Is this a defect of the C++ standard? Or is there any  rationale for that?

Comment: @xmllmx: that's just the way namespaces work, I don't think it's a defect

Comment: @xmllmx: because argument dependent lookup occurs at the point of template instantiation (which in the problematic case is in the namespace `std`)

Comment: @icecrime, thank you very much for your quick answer and patient explanations.