# Why "std::accumulate" needs explicit overloaded "operator+"?

Tags: c++, stl

I have overloaded `operator+` in my code,

```
template < class T1, class T2 >
inline std::pair < T1, T2 > operator+ ( const std::pair < T1, T2 > & a, const std::pair < T1, T2 > & b )
{
    return std::make_pair < T1, T2 > ( a.first + b.first, a.second + b.second );
}
```

However, below fails

```
vector < pair < int, int > > v ( n );
accumulate ( v.begin( ), v.end( ), make_pair ( 0, 0 ) );
```

with the compiler complaining that

```
... stl_numeric.h:128:2: error: no match for 'operator+' in  ...
```

and forces an explicit form as below:

```
accumulate ( v.begin( ), v.end( ), make_pair ( 0, 0 ), operator+< int, int> );
```

My question: Why I need to provide `operator+` explicitly?

In particular why the line below works like a charm when `accumulate` fails?

```
make_pair ( 2, 3 ) + make_pair ( 5, 7)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried without templating the operator?

Comment: Probably because of dependent name lookup. The lookup in `std::accumulate` will only find an `operator+` that is declared before the definition of `std::accumulate` or in an namespace associated with its arguments (the global namespace is *not* associated with `std::pair`).

Comment: This might be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4447827/420683)

Comment: [SSCCE](http://ideone.com/vo9trN).

Comment: "Wrapping the overload definition with namespace std { ... } solves the issue. thanks folks." Unfortunately, this isn't a solution: [namespace.std]/1 "The behavior of a C ++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are defining an operator working on types defined in namespace `std` outside of this namespace. This makes sense because you are not allowed to overload it as general as you do in namespace `std`: it needs to involve at least one user-defined type to be allowed to overload it namespace `std`).

When templates are instantiated functions depending on a template argument are only found using argument dependent look-up. ADL only finds names in the namespaces associated with the arguments. In your example the only associated namespace is `std`.

Comment: "it needs to involve at least one user-defined type to be allowed to overload it namespace `std`" Wow, that's news to me. I thought only specializations were allowed. Did this change recently?

Comment: @DyP: Specialization are only allowed *if they involve at least one user-defined type*.  The rule you remember and the one Dietmar is using aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, but the OP's example is not a specialization.

Comment: @DyP: That's true.  Overloading `std::operator+` wouldn't be allowed (or required, since an overload can go in the namespace of the user-defined type).  Specializing `std::plus` would be allowed for user-defined types, but `std::accumulate` doesn't use `plus`; not sure if it would be better if it did.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are right: a program isn't allowed to overload a function in namespace `std` because there is no need to do so: it can be overloaded in a namespace involving a yser provided type.