# std::ostream_iterator does not find operator<<

Tags: c++, iterator, operators, operator-overloading

I have declared an `operator<<` for `std::pair<int, int>`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    o << p.first << p.second;
    return o;
}
```

I want to use this operator when i print my data:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> data;
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int, int>>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

But the compiler says, `no match for operator<<` ...
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Note that if you have a type T in names pace N, to use the ostream_iterator + copy combination, your operator << for T needs to be in name space N not in ::.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::copy` cannot find overloading for `operator <<` for `std::pair` in `std` namespace. There is no good way, to overload `operator <<` for object from `std` namespace in algorithms from `std` namespace.

You can use `std::for_each` with functor, that will print your values, for example with lambda.

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const std::pair<int, int>& p)
{
   std::cout << p << std::endl;
});
```

You cannot put overloading in std namespace, you can only add specializations for user-defined types since

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
> namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified
>
> A program may add a template specialization
> for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
> and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
> prohibited.

Comment: I see... So, what workaround would you suggest? Iterating over and printing manually seems not too elegant compared to `std::copy`.

Comment: @WonderCsabo use `std::for_each` with functor.

Comment: And what about this? I put my operator into std namespace. It works, but it seems little bit hacky.

Comment: @WonderCsabo You should never put something in std namespace. It's not allowed by standard.

Comment: You can put specializations of templates for user defined types in `std` namespace.

Comment: You could write a for loop. It would be two lines of code. Why this is inelegant is beyond me.

Comment: @john you can put specialization, but it doesn't matter in this case, since there is no operator << for T type in std namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447827/why-does-ostream-iterator-not-work-as-expected):

```
struct PAIR : std::pair<int, int>
{
  using std::pair<int, int>::pair;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> data;
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<PAIR>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

---

Since there's already a good answer, I will simply quote the link:

> The problem is that the name lookup does not find your
>   operator<<(ostream& os, const PAIR& r). The code that tries to invoke
>   the operator<< is in somewhere inside the ostream_iterator<> which is
>   itself inside the std namespace. The name lookup looks around for the
>   right function inside ostream_iterator<> and the std namespace; the
>   argument dependent lookup does not help here because both of the
>   parameters are in the std namespace, too.
>
> So, my suggestion is (1) either to wrap your operator into namespace
>   std { }, but that is UB, IIRC. Or (2) create a struct inheriting from
>   std::pair to define a new type in your namespace, and using the ADL to
>   find your operator<<().

---

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    o << p.first << p.second;
    return o;
}

struct PAIR : std::pair<int, int>
{
    using std::pair<int, int>::pair;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > data;
data.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(50, 42));
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<PAIR>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Wonder Yeah you need C++11. The other option (as posted in the link) is a stream manipulator.

Comment: @Wonder Let me post the full code sample that compiled for me.

Comment: I just tried your complete code. I got `error: 'std::pair<int, int>::pair' names constructor`. By the way i am using MINGW 4.7.2, maybe it does not supports this feature, yet.

Comment: @Wonder It works on both [ideone](http://ideone.com/gAP2UE) and [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d641ff4b3ac3d07c) for me. Ah, I'm using 4.8.1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42215/discussion-between-wondercsabo-and-remyabel)

Answer (score 1):

The general case for those who's Google search brought you to the specific case...

Note that if you have a type T in names pace N, to use the ostream_iterator + copy combination, your operator << for T needs to be in name space N not in ::.

```
namespace N {
    class T;
    std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &; T const & );
}
```

In this case std::copy can find your define N::operator <<( std::ostream &; T const & )

You don't need to worry about qualifying access when you use the operator.

```
N::T t;
std::cout << t << std::endl;
```

and

```
std::list<N::t> alist;
alist.push_back(t);

std::ostream_iterator<N::t> out_itr(std::cout, "\n");
std::copy(alist.begin(), alist.end(), out_itr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > data;
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >(std::cout, "\n"));
```

please try this, i think there has a space between `>`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem at all. C++11 allows this syntax.