# Overhit output operator for string pointer in vector

Tags: c++, overriding, output

I have vector that contains pointers to string `vector<string*>` and I want to use `ostream_iterator` to output strings value. I try to override `<<` operator but it doesn't work:
`std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, string* p) {
    return os << *p;
}`. It still output variables adreses.

Comment: Where do you put this, and where do you (want to) use it?

Comment: Comedy option: `std::transform(begin(vec), end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<string>, [](const std::string* foo){return *foo});` And I hope I got it right. ;-)

Comment: @Xarn it looks like you did, and that's *awesome*. I was about to pound out a `std::for_each` but I like that so much better =P

Comment: @WhozCraig I actually didn't, notice missing `(std::cout)` (or other stream) for the `ostream_iterator` and missing semicolon in lambda. I blame lack of coffee. :-) On a more serious note, [a quick test with coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb0fa4c3ea49aba6) shows that specializing `<<` for `std::string*` seems to work properly.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447827/why-does-ostream-iterator-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not quite clear what you are actually asking, but your specialization of `<<` [works for me when tested.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb0fa4c3ea49aba6) That is, this works as expected:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::string* p){
    return os << *p;
}


int main(){

    std::string str("Hello World\n");
    std::vector<std::string*> vec{&str};


    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        std::cout << vec[i];
    }
```

output is `Hello World`.

However, for a bit more fun, you can do a nice, idiomatic oneliner:

```
std::transform(begin(vec), end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout), [](const std::string* foo){return *foo;});
```

You can replace `std::cout` in the example with any output stream you want.

Comment: he tries to output like this `std::ostream_iterator<string*> out_it (std::cout,", ");std::copy ( some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(), out_it );`

Comment: @EmilCondrea Assuming you are right, that would explain it.